# How can iterate & compare 2 pandas columns based on datetime & add a value of true or false?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime, boolean

I have a pandas dataframe that contains 2 columns: Predicted time & Actual times. I would like a third column that contains true or false values. In other words, if for every predicted time row the time matches one of the actual times in that same row OR the predicted time lies in-between one of those actual times, then add a 'True' to the third column value. Else, add a 'False' in the row.

Any ideas where to begin? I assume this requires two things: datetime module for comparing & iterating through every row to produce the newly written row value?

**Current dataframe:**

```
;Predicted time;Actual times
0;[2017-09-09 06:53:37, 2017-09-09 06:53:46];[2017-09-09 06:54:11, 2017-09-09 06:54:21,] [2017-09-09 06:54:29, 2017-09-09 06:55:14], [2017-09-09 06:55:30, 2017-09-09 06:55:51]]
1;[2017-09-09 06:54:19, 2017-09-09 06:54:43];[2017-09-09 06:54:11, 2017-09-09 06:54:21, 2017-09-09 06:54:29, 2017-09-09 06:55:14, 2017-09-09 06:55:30, 2017-09-09 06:55:51]
2;[2017-09-09 06:54:44, 2017-09-09 06:54:48];[2017-09-09 06:54:11, 2017-09-09 06:54:21,] [2017-09-09 06:54:29, 2017-09-09 06:55:14], [2017-09-09 06:55:30, 2017-09-09 06:55:51]]
```

**Desired output**

```
;Predicted time;Actual times;True or False
0;[2017-09-09 06:53:37, 2017-09-09 06:53:46];[2017-09-09 06:54:11, 2017-09-09 06:54:21,] [2017-09-09 06:54:29, 2017-09-09 06:55:14], [2017-09-09 06:55:30, 2017-09-09 06:55:51]];FALSE
1;[2017-09-09 06:54:19, 2017-09-09 06:54:43];[2017-09-09 06:54:11, 2017-09-09 06:54:21, 2017-09-09 06:54:29, 2017-09-09 06:55:14, 2017-09-09 06:55:30, 2017-09-09 06:55:51];TRUE
2;[2017-09-09 06:54:44, 2017-09-09 06:54:48];[2017-09-09 06:54:11, 2017-09-09 06:54:21,] [2017-09-09 06:54:29, 2017-09-09 06:55:14], [2017-09-09 06:55:30, 2017-09-09 06:55:51]];TRUE
```

I have also attached an image to show the desired output more clearly.

[image]

Comment: can you provide the input as DataFrame constructor? It is currently ambiguous (string? lists?…)

Comment: you can copy-paste the csv format of the dataframe, save is as a csv and open it in python as follows: ```pd.read_csv('example.csv', delimiter=';')```

Comment: the datetimes are the string result of the datetime object

Comment: So, it's text? I know how to read and convert the data. I just don't know what is the input in your case ;)

Comment: ah sorry, I understood your question incorrectly, my bad. The input is strings that can be read & reformatted using the datetime module. So like, [datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 9, 6, 53, 37, 525000)] becomes a string ['2017-09-09 06:53:37'] --> Pandas transforms this in this way. Hope it makes more sense :)

Comment: @blah - last is not `False` ?

Comment: What happens if the predicted time interval only intersects but is not a subset of any of the actual times? I mean - `predicted_time = [00:04:04, 00:04:59]` and `actual_times = [[00:04:01, 00:04:06]]`

Comment: That can also be considered 'True'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the work in the function below is to convert the strings in your dataframe to a collection of `datetime` objects that can be used for comparison -

```
def pred_intersects_act(row):
    #Convert predicted times to list of datetime objects
    predicted_time = re.sub(r'\[|\]', '', row['predicted_time'])
    predicted_time = re.sub(r',\ *', ',', predicted_time)
    pt_list = predicted_time.split(',')
    pt_list = [dt.strptime(_, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for _ in pt_list]

    #Convert actual times to list of datetime objects
    actual_times = re.sub(r'\[|\]', '', row['actual_times'])
    actual_times = re.sub(r',\ *', ',', actual_times)
    at_list = actual_times.split(',')
    at_list = [dt.strptime(_, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for _ in at_list]

    #pair up actual times and check for intersection
    for pair in zip(at_list[:-1], at_list[1:]):
        exact_match = any(_ in pair for _ in pt_list)
        approx_match = any(bisect.bisect(pair, _) == 1 for _ in pt_list)
        if exact_match or approx_match:
            return True
    return False

df.apply(pred_intersects_act, axis=1)
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with test values between with `any` for test at least one `True`:

```
#for converting to datetimes, in Actual times was removed nested lists
f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.strip('[]').split(', ')).tolist()
df[['Actual times', 'Predicted time']] = df[['Actual times', 'Predicted time']].applymap(f)

df['True or False'] = [any((s < y) & (e > y) for y in x) 
                        for (s, e), x in zip(df['Predicted time'], df['Actual times'])]
print (df)
                               Predicted time  \
0  [2017-09-09 06:53:37, 2017-09-09 06:53:46]   
1  [2017-09-09 06:54:19, 2017-09-09 06:54:43]   
2  [2017-09-09 06:54:44, 2017-09-09 06:54:48]   

                                        Actual times  True or False  
0  [2017-09-09 06:54:11, 2017-09-09 06:54:21, 201...          False  
1  [2017-09-09 06:54:11, 2017-09-09 06:54:21, 201...           True  
2  [2017-09-09 06:54:11, 2017-09-09 06:54:21, 201...          False
```